# Laravel destroy and update methods nothing happend

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I've copied my code from another Contoller, where everything work, but here it doesn't work, i don't know why. A can create about us, but when i click destroy - nothing happens and when I am trying to update it's redirect me to "Create about us".

AboutUsController:

```
    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\AboutUs $aboutUs
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(AboutUs $aboutUs)
    {
        return view('auth.aboutus.form',compact('aboutUs'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\AboutUs $aboutUs
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(AboutUsRequest $request, AboutUs $aboutUs)
    {
        $params = $request->all();

        $aboutUs->update($request->all($params));

        return redirect()->route('aboutUs.index')->with('success','Post updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\AboutUs $aboutUs
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(AboutUs $aboutUs)
    {
        $aboutUs->delete();

        return redirect()->route('aboutUs.index')
            ->with('success','blog deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

aboutUs/index.blade.php:

```
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                            <form action="{{ route('aboutUs.destroy', $about) }}" method="POST">
                                <a class="btn btn-warning" type="button"
                                   href="{{ route('aboutUs.edit', $about) }}">Update</a>
                                @csrf
                                @method('DELETE')
                                <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete"></form>
                        </div>
                    </td>
```

Here is my routes, i think the problem is actualy here, because when I list my routes it is show for example aboutus/{aboutU}, when my variable is aboutUs
web.php:

```
Route::group([
            'namespace' => 'Admin',
            'prefix' => 'admin',
        ], function () {
            Route::group(['middleware' => 'is_admin'], function () {
                Route::get('/contacts', 'ContactController@index')->name('emails.contactus');
                Route::get('/orders', 'OrderController@index')->name('home');
                Route::get('/orders/{order}', 'OrderController@show')->name('orders.show');

            });
            Route::resource('blogs', 'BlogController');
            Route::resource('aboutUs', 'AboutUsController');
            Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController');
Route::group([
            'namespace' => 'Admin',
            'prefix' => 'admin',
        ], function () {
            Route::group(['middleware' => 'is_admin'], function () {
                Route::get('/contacts', 'ContactController@index')->name('emails.contactus');
                Route::get('/orders', 'OrderController@index')->name('home');
                Route::get('/orders/{order}', 'OrderController@show')->name('orders.show');

            });
            Route::resource('blogs', 'BlogController');
            Route::resource('aboutUs', 'AboutUsController');
            Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController');
```

Comment: Did you copy your code twice for routes?

Comment: Do you mean i have two similar routes?

Comment: In you route code snippet there are 2 same routes

Comment: @gguney one is aboutUs for admin and one is aboutus for show data for users. Is they the same?

Comment: but both are the same aren't they? You grouped them by admin namespace and prefix

Comment: @gguney i've changed second route, nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is in the update method. you only have `$params` when you want to get request in AboutUsController.

So this is the correct code:

AboutUsController

```
public function update(AboutUsRequest $request, AboutUs $aboutUs)
{
    $params = $request->all();

    $aboutUs->update($params);

    return redirect()->route('aboutUs.index')->with('success','Post updated successfully');
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: there is a method called authorize in the form request. You may not have changed this method and your request has not permission. This could be the reason for returning to the index route.
If not, you need to ask your question more precisely.